# C# inheritance, custom controls, templates, converters, and dependency properties and getting them to all play nicely

Tags: c#, binding, dependency-properties

I have three classes `Assignment` (abstract), `CourseAssignment`, and `StudentAssignment`.  `StudentAssignment` and `CourseAssignment` both inherit from the abstract `Assignment` class.

I have a complex style where I have reformatted the look and feel of the WPF calendar, but I want assignments to show up in my calendar, so I have created a custom control (call it `MyCalendar`, which inherits from Calendar, but adds a dependency property (see code below) which allows me to bind an assignment list to the calendar.

```
public static DependencyProperty AssignmentsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
        ("Assignments",typeof(ObservableCollection<Assignment>),typeof(Calendar));

    public ObservableCollection<Assignment> Assignments
    { 
        get {return (ObservableCollection<Assignment>)GetValue(AssignmentsProperty);} 
        set {SetValue(AssignmentsProperty, value); }
    }
```

Depending on which tab control I place the calendar control, the binding is going to be either to an observable collection of `StudentAssignment` or `CourseAssignment`.  The calendar shouldn't really care if the assignment list is a `CourseAssignment` or `StudentAssignment` list, because all it needs is the due date and description (both properties are in the base abstract class), but herein lies my problem.  I am using a IMultiValueConverter to put the assignments onto the correct day

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ObservableCollection<Assignment>), typeof(ObservableCollection<Assignment>))]
public class AssignmentConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)values[1];
        ObservableCollection<Assignment> assignments = new ObservableCollection<Assignment>();

        foreach (Assignment assignment in (ObservableCollection<Assignment>)values[0])
        {
            if (assignment.DueDate.Date == date)
            {
                assignments.Add(assignment);
            }
        }
        return assignments;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**What is the best way to get my binding to work?**  I know I want to set the binding to the observable collection, but if I do it in XAML, I get `cannot convert from observablecollection(CourseAssignment) to observablecollection(Assignment)` error; I need to somehow convert the collection of CourseAssignments to a collection of Assignments before I do the binding, right?  What is the best way to do that?

Comment: out of curiosity, have you thought about making Assignment an IAssignment interface instead of a abstract class?  That would fix your issue quick, to have an observablecollection of IAssignment instead

Comment: No, I hadn't thought of that.  The two classes are so closely related that they fit nicely into inheritance.  I have never really liked using interfaces in the past because I hate repeating code if I can help it at all.  But I can give it a try.  Thanks for the advice.